# CheckBox gets Checked when its Text is clicked

Tags: android

I have a checkbox and i don't want it be checked when the user click's its text. It should only be checked when the button is clicked.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Dont have much experience about the `CheckBox` control.

But i think.

You can make *checkbox without giving names/text* and put a `TextView` to *rightof the checkbox* as the name/text of that checkbox.

Ex.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am already using this step but i want it to be simple. That's the reason i asked this question.

Comment: simple means? you dont want to use another textview ?

Comment: yes, I don't want to use another textview. I just want the checkbox itself. Current i am using a checkbox with no text value and a textview placed to its right with the text.

Answer (score 0):

It is by default i think.You can remove text of checkbox and put a textView beside it.This trick may work. :)